# jQuery Tabs Errors

Tags: c#, jquery, tabs

I am trying to jQuery tabs in C#. Here is the script sources and stylesheet which I included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#reportTabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

And here is where I set up my jQuery tabs:

```
     <div id="reportTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#mainContent_statusDiv">By Region</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mainContent_exeDiv">Execution Status Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mainContent_dueDiv">Due in 30 Days</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mainContent_rangeDiv">Due in 30-90 Days</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mainContent_areaDiv">By Service Area</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="statusDiv" runat="server">

    </div>
    <div id="exeDiv" runat="server">

    </div>
    <div id="dueDiv" runat="server">

    </div>
</div>
```

But somehow when I try to run the page, it tells me an error message which is: `mismatching fragment identifier`. I wonder which part went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change the HTML and try, hopefully it should work, I guess `mainContent_` in `href` is playing culprit

```
<div id="reportTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#statusDiv">By Region</a></li>
        <li><a href="#exeDiv">Execution Status Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#dueDiv">Due in 30 Days</a></li>
        <li><a href="#rangeDiv">Due in 30-90 Days</a></li>
        <li><a href="#areaDiv">By Service Area</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="statusDiv" runat="server">
        1
    </div>
    <div id="exeDiv" runat="server">
        2
    </div>
    <div id="dueDiv" runat="server">
        3
    </div>
    <div id="rangeDiv" runat="server">
        4
    </div>
    <div id="areaDiv" runat="server">
        5
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/TLB79/
Please check external resources for JS and CSS URL

Comment: Hi, I have removed the mainContent, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: add remaining rangeDiv and areaDiv (4, 5) divs and check

Comment: I created demo with your code, hope it helps, there might be some other issue with your page code which might be preventing creations of tabs